# yq: Sorting a slice of an array in a YAML file

Tags: shell, command-line, yaml, slice, yq

Sample `file.yml`:

```yaml
---
- foo: bar
  bing:
    - bong
    - bang
  people:
    - { name: pin, nicknames: ['pin', 'first'] }
    - { name: deb, nicknames: ['deb'] }
    - { name: roger, nicknames: ['roger'] }
    - { name: kenny, nicknames: ['kenny'] }
    - { name: annie, nicknames: ['annie'] }
```

I'm trying to use yq to sort `people` objects by `name`, except for `pin` which should stay first.

Desired output:

```yaml
---
- foo: bar
  bing:
    - bong
    - bang
  people:
    - { name: pin, nicknames: ['pin', 'first'] }
    - { name: annie, nicknames: ['annie'] }
    - { name: deb, nicknames: ['deb'] }
    - { name: kenny, nicknames: ['kenny'] }
    - { name: roger, nicknames: ['roger'] }
```

```bash
❯ yq -V
yq (https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/) version v4.31.2
```

I got as far as slicing and sorting but that only prints the sorted slice:

```yaml
❯ yq '.[].people.[1:] | sort_by(.name)' file.yml
- {name: annie, nicknames: ['annie']}
- {name: deb, nicknames: ['deb']}
- {name: kenny, nicknames: ['kenny']}
- {name: roger, nicknames: ['roger']}
```

Not sure how to get the rest back in, or if I'm even on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `❯ yq '.[].people.[1:] | sort_by(.name)' file.yml`

Actually, changing only `|` to `|=` in order to [update](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/assign-update) the array slice while retaining the original context, should do the job (and it indeed does with [kislyuk/yq](https://github.com/kislyuk/yq)). With [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq), however, the array for some reason is returned unsorted:

```bash
yq '.[].people.[1:] |= sort_by(.name)' file.yml
```

```yaml
---
- foo: bar
  bing:
    - bong
    - bang
  people:
    - {name: pin, nicknames: ['pin', 'first']}
    - {name: deb, nicknames: ['deb']}
    - {name: roger, nicknames: ['roger']}
    - {name: kenny, nicknames: ['kenny']}
    - {name: annie, nicknames: ['annie']}
```

So, instead, you could do it manually by slicing off the first item, then re-adding it to the independently sorted array slice:

```bash
yq '.[].people |= .[:1] + (.[1:] | sort_by(.name))' file.yml
```

```yaml
---
- foo: bar
  bing:
    - bong
    - bang
  people:
    - {name: pin, nicknames: ['pin', 'first']}
    - {name: annie, nicknames: ['annie']}
    - {name: deb, nicknames: ['deb']}
    - {name: kenny, nicknames: ['kenny']}
    - {name: roger, nicknames: ['roger']}
```

Comment: That doesn't sort, as your snippet shows. That output is identical to the input.

Comment: @remnant24 You might see an old version of the post. I have updated it 15 minutes ago with an alternative.

Comment: `yq '.[].people |= .[:1] + (.[1:] | sort_by(.name))' file.yml` nails it. Big thanks.